# Angular How to use data from json in c3?

Tags: json, angularjs, d3.js, c3.js

I have a problem with showing data from json in c3.
I send data from express and I can get it in `./behavior`
Here is my angular controller:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('GraphCtrl', function ($scope) {

   d3.json('./behavior', function(err, data){
    if(err){ throw err; }
    $scope.data = data;
    console.log(data);
    $scope.$apply();

    $scope.chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#behavior',
    data: {
        columns: [],
        type: 'bar',

        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.4 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
            }
        },
        grid: {
            x: {
                show: true
            },
            y: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        color: {
            pattern: ['#FF9800', '#8BC34A', '#E040FB', '#3F51B5', '#FF4081']
        }
    });
});
```

and I bind it to HTML:

```
<div id="graph" ng-controller="BehaviorGraphCtrl">
    <div id="behavior"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
data: {
        columns: [],
        type: 'bar'
    }
```

You haven't added `$scope.data` in columns.

Change it to

```
data: {
        columns: $scope.data,
        type: 'bar'
    }
```

Here `$scope.data` should be array and in proper format.

Check Getting Started [Guide](http://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html) demo for `Columns`

Comment: I changed, but it still doesn't work. The data (two objects in array) which I want to show on graph: [{"calling_number":"123","play":"OFF"},{"calling_number":"321","play":"ON"}] Do I have to parse this data to show?

Comment: Your data is not proper...That's why it's not working...There is no object in array in demo example....

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ormW9jDCVwV4CfxKTow?p=preview), no graph unfortunately

Comment: Please take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/maxklenk/k9Dbf/), there are objects in array.

Comment: You have to specify some params based on requirement...Look at [this](http://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html) example or from your fiddle example, try to set some params based on your object

Answer (score 0):

Instead of columns attribute, in data object I added `json` and `keys` attributes and the working result is:

```
data: {
    json: $scope.data,
    keys: {
          value: ['units', 'duration'],
    },
    type: 'bar'
}
```

Thanks for your help.